# which SWT component use to implement file browser/explorator in icons, not list, mode

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

how to implement a file browser which has explorator windows/nautilus(Linux) like functionality. I'm looking for a concept which component I should use as a base to create something like right side of this application: http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/demos/local_file_explorer.aspx

I need to implement it in SWT, it should work on Windows and Linux at once.

Answer (score 0):

If JFace is fine with you then have a look at these links (otherwise you can study the sample code to write the SWT version): (The below links are dead now)

1. <strike>http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecgui1/</strike>
2. <strike>http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecgui2/</strike>

The final output of the above tutorial looks like this:

[image]

Also have a look at the [official examples](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php) from eclipse. There is a sample file explorer bundled with it. See the below image:

[image]

Comment: Its nice but first two links are dead. Are these are plugin?Can we integrate this in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I think those were simple java apps (not very sure..its been three years and I moved on). If you want a plugin like this and its very easy to write one :)